# Ampersand (for matrix align) still appear in math mode in minted, listings?

Tags: math-mode, minted, alignment, ampersand

Here is the tex code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||,mathescape=true, breaklines]{python}
# $\begin{vmatrix}\lambda _{a_1}^{b_1} & \dots & \lambda _{a_1}^{b_p}\\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\\lambda _{a_p}^{b_1} & \dots & \lambda _{a_p}^{b_p}\end{vmatrix}$
\end{minted}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside=||,mathescape=true, breaklines]{python}
# $\begin{vmatrix}\lambda _{a_1}^{b_1} & \dots & \lambda _{a_1}^{b_p}\\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\\lambda _{a_p}^{b_1} & \dots & \lambda _{a_p}^{b_p}\end{vmatrix}$
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

And here is the output

[image]

How to remove `&` from output?

Comment: As `mathescape` is on, you should use `&` instead of the escaped `\&`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Sorry, I use `&` at first, but not work, so I try to use `\&`, then copy code to the question. Already changed to `&` in the question.

Comment: You might do `\newcommand{\TAB}{&}` in the preamble and use `\TAB` instead of `&` for things inside the scope of math escape in `minted`.

Comment: @egreg Thank! In my preamble setup (not in the preamble setup of this question), it alarm error `Command \TAB already defined`, so I change to another keyword like `\newcommand{\apsand}{&}`, and it work. Is there any reason to prefer keyword `\TAB`.

Comment: @ydhhat No, any name is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be an issue in the [latex formatter of `pygments`](https://github.com/pygments/pygments/blob/22131277ce57ebaeebf4a102b811aad6d4cacecc/pygments/formatters/latex.py#L343-L345). Currently, when `mathescape` is used, the generated `Verbatim` environment will look like

```tex
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},codes={\catcode`\$=3\catcode`\^=7\catcode`\_=8\relax}]
<verbatim content>
\end{Verbatim}
```

Here in `fancyvrb` option `codes={...}` the category code of `&` is not restored, hence still in `12` (other) and you see the verbatim `&` character in output.

A workaround for both `minted` and `fvextra` packages:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{\Verb|minted| and \Verb|Verbatim| envs, actual}

\begin{minted}[mathescape]{python}
# catcode of & = $\text{\the\catcode`\&}, \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{vmatrix}$
\end{minted}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}, mathescape]
# catcode of & = $\text{\the\catcode`\&}, \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{vmatrix}$
\end{Verbatim}

\makeatletter
% This patches fvextra option "mathescape", but unfortunately it won't work
% for minted, since the pygments-generated (till v2.16.1) "Verbatim" env
% always drop "mathescape" option and use its own "codes={...}" settings.
%
% See https://github.com/pygments/pygments/issues/1988
\appto\FV@MathEscape{\catcode`\&=4\relax}

% This workaround works for minted (v2.8).
\FV@AddToHook\FV@CatCodesHook{%
  % if inside a minted with mathescape, change catcode of &
  \ifthenelse{%
    \(\NOT{\isundefined{\minted@cmd}}\)% used to determin if inside a minted
    \AND
    \equal{\minted@get@opt{mathescape}{false}}{true}}
    {\catcode`\&=4\relax}
    {}%
}
\makeatother

\subsection*{\Verb|minted| and \Verb|Verbatim| envs, with workaround}
\begin{minted}[mathescape, breaklines]{python}
# minted with mathescape
# catcode of & = $\text{\the\catcode`\&}, \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{vmatrix}$
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[breaklines]{python}
# minted, no mathescape
# catcode of & = $\text{\the\catcode`\&}, \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{vmatrix}$
\end{minted}

% NOTE:
% Using "mathescape" now causes all occurances of $, ^, _, and in addition &
% gain their normal catcodes in verbatim content.
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}, mathescape, breaklines]
# Verbatim with mathescape, now \& outside of \$...\$ has to be escaped
# catcode of \& = $\text{\the\catcode`\&}, \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{vmatrix}$
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[breaklines]
# Verbatim, no mathescape
# catcode of & = $\text{\the\catcode`\&}, \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{vmatrix}$
\end{Verbatim}

\subsection*{\Verb|lstlisting| env}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily, escapeinside=||, mathescape, breaklines]{python}
# catcode of & = $\text{\the\catcode`\&}, \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{vmatrix}$
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Edition history

- Dec 11, 2021, I opened https://github.com/pygments/pygments/issues/1988 in `pygments` repo which suggested addition of `` \catcode`\&=4 ``. No progress by Sep 28, 2023.
- Sep 28, 2023, the answer is updated with a more robust workaround and I hence opened https://github.com/gpoore/fvextra/issues/18 in `fvextra` repo to see if `fvextra` will restore catcode of `&` with `mathescape` automatically.
  If so, I would suggest `pygments` to pass `mathescape` option to `Verbatim` environment, instead of always drop it and use `codes={...}`.
- Oct 1, 2023, apply the patch conditionally.

[image]

Comment: I've reported this to `pygments`: https://github.com/pygments/pygments/issues/1988